# How to read characters in from a file from right to left

Tags: java

I am working on a program that evaluates lisp expressions using a stack implemented by either an array or linked list.  I need to read the file in from the first line from right to left.  Currently I am reading it in from left to right but I do not understand how I can switch it around.  Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**I know the program is nowhere near complete, I just need to accomplish this before I can continue.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;


public class A2Q5{
    private static Scanner in;


    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        if(args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Please execute as: java A2Q5 type infile");
        }

        BoundedStack<Double> stack;
        if(args[0].equals("0"))
            stack = new BSArray<Double>(20);
        else
            stack = new BSLinkedList<Double>();


        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = args[1];

        // This will reference one line at a time
        //char c = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

                for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                    line.charAt(i);
                    System.out.println(line.charAt(i));
                }
            }

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file " + fileName);                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file " + fileName);                 

        }

    }     
}
```

Comment: You're reading character by character... Why not read line by line, then reverse the line?

Comment: But then how can I read each character individually?

Comment: You read the line, then implement a for loop that goes from the last index to the first index: `for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`  Then access the individual characters using `str.charAt(i)` OR you reverse the line, then access each character with a foreach loop: `for (Character c : str)`

Comment: There is `reverse()` method in `StringBuilder` class...Also, I think you can use `Character.isDigit()`...see if it helps.

Comment: Why are you opening the file for reading twice? Remove `fileInput` and use `bufferedReader.readLine()`, then follow suggestion by @SaviourSelf.

Comment: Note that `fileInput` is a raw byte stream, not a character stream, so non-ASCII characters will be misinterpreted.

Comment: I have implemented the above code and it works! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Drop the use of FileInputStream and use BufferedReader that you already prepared but never use. Use its method readLine to read info from your file line by line. Once you got an individual line you can iterate through it character by character from the end of the String to its beginning. This is exactly what you want.